# Botframework v4 Directline integration: Is there a way to get the conversation id generated from directline transfer to the Chatbot (nodejs code)

Tags: node.js, botframework, direct-line-botframework

This might be very simple, but I cannot find any reference regarding this. 
I integrated the chat bot in the web app using direct line API; I’m using this API to generate conversation id:

POST: https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations

I’m trying to get the generated conversation id from the above API (from web app code) to the chatbot code (NodeJS). Is there a way or any reference to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it using Botframework Web Chat back channel, here's the link for reference:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

After I generated the conversation id using directline API:
POST: https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations

I send data from the web app to the chatbot via backchannel.

```
<div id="webchat"></div>
<script>
  (async function () {
    // We are using a customized store to add hooks to connect event
    const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
      if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
        // When we receive DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED action, we will send an event activity using WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT
        dispatch({
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
          payload: {
            name: 'webchat/join',
            value: { conversation_id: conversationID }
          }
        });
      }

      return next(action);
    });

    window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
      directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
      store
    }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

    document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
  })().catch(err => console.error(err));

  //Note: conversationID and token is generated in the backend code of the web app.
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way as per [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/357#issuecomment-284711267) issue comment is to send data to bot before starting the conversation using:

```
var params = BotChat.queryParams(location.search);
var my_token = params['my_token'];

var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
    secret: 'DIRECTLINE_SECRET'
});

BotChat.App({
    botConnection: botConnection
    ,user: { id: 'USER_ID', name: 'User' }  // user.id auto updates after first user message
}, document.getElementById("bot"));

botConnection.connectionStatus$.subscribe(function (status) {
    if (status == 2) {  // wait for connection is 'OnLine' to send data to bot
        var convID = botConnection.conversationId;
        botConnection.postActivity({
            from: { id: convID }  // because first time user ID == conversation ID
            ,type: 'event'
            ,name: 'registerUserData'    // event name as we need
            ,value: my_token   // data attached to event
        }).subscribe(function (activityId) {
            // This subscription is a MUST
            // If I remove this handler the postActivity not reaches the bot
        });
    }
});
```

Here you subscribe to the botConnection.connectionStatus$ and when the status is equal to 2, you get the conversation ID from the botConnection object.

Then, you can add this middleware code in the bot code to get the data:

```
bot.use({ receive: function(event, next) {
    if (!!event && !!event.address && event.name == 'registerUserData') {
        var message = new builder.Message().address(event.address).text('my_token:' + event.value);
        bot.send(message, function (err) {});  // simulate proactive message to user
    }
    next();
} });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, if you found the answer helpful, can you please accept it so that it helps others? Thanks

Comment: I think the sample that you provided above is applicable for botframework older version. I'm currently developing with botframework v4.